embedAndSignAppleFrameworkForXcode script failing for KMP with cocoapods integration
Following the official docs on how to support cocoapods in KMP projects, you will eventually get an error even on a sample application:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:

'embedAndSign' task can't be used in a project with dependencies to pods.

Please migrate to CocoaPods for integration into Xcode: https://kotl.in/vc2iq3

To temporarily suppress this error, put the following in your gradle.properties:

The link above goes to the official docs:
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/native-cocoapods-xcode.html#xcode-project-with-one-target
But they miss the solution.
I was expecting to see build running.

Finally I found an answer. It is simple, but not mentioned anywhere...
Just open xcode project file in any editor and instead
shellScript = "cd \"$SRCROOT/..\"\n./gradlew :composeApp:embedAndSignAppleFrameworkForXcode\n";

put
shellScript = "";

You can do the same via xcode UI, but it is much quicker to do it this way.
This script is a leftover existing there due to direct integration (that is in all samples by default): https://kotlinlang.org/docs/multiplatform-direct-integration.html
